# How to bootstrap a JSON configuration file for an Angular 2 module without using a http.get approach

Tags: json, angular, typescript, configuration, bootstrapping

I have one json file at root:

config.json

```
{ "base_url": "http://localhost:3000" }
```

and in my service class, I want to use it in this way:

```
private productsUrl = config.base_url + 'products';
```

I've found a ton of posts with either solutions that require a http.get request to load that one file to get that one variable or outdated solutions for angular.js (angular 1)

I cant believe there isnt an easier way to include this file that we already have in place without having to make an additional request to the server.

In my opinion, I would have expected that at least the bootstrapping function would be able to provide this kind of functionality, something like:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { config: config.json });
```

btw, this works, but its not the ideal solution:

```
export class Config {
  static base_url: string = "http://localhost:3004/";
}
```

and the use it where you need it:

```
private productsUrl = Config.base_url + 'products';
```

Its not ideal, because I will have to create the class (or replace properties) in a build script.  (exactly what I was thinking to do with the config.json file).

I still prefer the config.json file approach, since it would not be intrusive with the TypeScript compiler.  Any ideas how to do are welcome and really appreciated!

Comment: You could look into how the Angular CLI manages its `.environment.ts` files, which is one solution to this problem - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files

Comment: that link refers only to the build process, I need the variables in the app runtime.  I already have the environment variables that I need in place for the build, the main problem is to inject those inside the app.

Comment: In that case it's going to depend a lot on how you're deploying the app, which you haven't mentioned yet. To get some env-specific state into a statically deployed Angular app we've used server-side includes, but it's not clear whether that will be an option for you.

Comment: I should actually be agnostic to the deployment process. The point is that whatever build ran first, it created a config.json file that has to be consumed by the Angular app without using http. Just imagine a existent block of code that has to be included in the app, you don't have to create it, its there already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using webpack? If you are, and you can just do

```
const config = require('./config.json');

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   private config:any = config;
   ....
}
```

in your webpack config you will need the json-loader

```
  ...
  module: {
    ...
    loaders: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ["json-loader"]
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Im using System.js, but if that works with webpack, I think I know how to adapt it on System.js. Let me check it this works, and yeah, this is most likely what I was looking for.  BTW, would it represent any sort of risk letting angular interpret json files directly? Im just curious why this support does not come out of the box.

Comment: What you're describing is fairly open ended.... an xhr to some json file. Angular is agnostic to your js.  jonrsharpe provided the 'out of the box' answer.

If the above approach is not adaptable to systemjs, and you really need an independent xhr request then consider:

so, instead of 

    doRunYourBootstrapCode()
 
you can do

    doLoadYourJsonWithHttpGet().then(json=>{
        doRunYourBootstrapCode(json);
    });

I'd try loading it through systemjs and whatever you're using for "packing" first, since it's one less call. Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome @eotoole, this is exactly what i was looking for. If I understand Angular as a "contained" set of javascript blocks/functions, it makes sense you need to instruct the module loader how to load json. Im adding the System.js version as an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This link explains how to use System.js to load json files in an angular app.](https://georgedyrra.wordpress.com/2017/02/09/loading-json-files-with-systemjs-module-loader/)

Special thanks to @eotoole that pointed me in the right direction.

If the link above is not clear enough, just add a map into the System.js conf. like this:

`map: { 'plugin-json': 'https://unpkg.com/systemjs-plugin-json' }`*

*(using external package)

or

`map: { 'plugin-json': 'plugin-json/json.js' }`**

**if you download the plugin from:

[official system.js plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-json)

now I can use:

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

anywere in my app.

and since it is official from the "systemjs" - guys, I feel comfortable using it to load app settings like base_url or other endpoints.

Now I need to figure out how to encapsulate this logic for testing purposes. Maybe requiring the file in its own class and replacing the values for the specific test case.